# iterate over two arrays in jsp using struts 2 tags

Tags: struts2

Can Anyone help me please.
My intention is to iterate over the two 2Dimentional arrays

1. `Org_Positions_IdTitle` which contains a)the ids of raised positions and b)their Titles.
2. `Org_Apps` which contains a)student Ids and b)ids of raised positions.

So I want whenever the position Ids in the two arrays are checked equal to display the Title of the position. Thanks a lot for your help guys.

```
  ResultSet ResSet_Org_Positions_IdTitle = OrgInfo.Get_Organisation_Positions_IdTitle(username,password);   
            ResultSet ResSet_Org_Apps = OrgInfo.Get_Organisation_Apps(username,password);

        int i=0;
        while(ResSet_Org_Positions_IdTitle.next()){ 
            Org_Positions_IdTitle[i][0] = new String(String.valueOf(ResSet_Org_Positions_IdTitle.getInt("P_Ps_Id")));
            Org_Positions_IdTitle[i][1]= new String(ResSet_Org_Positions_IdTitle.getString("Title")); i++;
            Org_Positions_IdTitle[i][0]= new String("Last");
            //System.out.println(i+":"+Org_Positions_IdTitle[i-1][j-1]+Org_Positions_IdTitle[i-1][j]);
        }

        int m=0; //Org_Apps A_St_Id A_Ps_Id
        while(ResSet_Org_Apps.next()){ 
            Org_Apps[m][0] = new String(String.valueOf(ResSet_Org_Apps.getInt("A_St_Id"))); 
            Org_Apps[m][1]= new String(ResSet_Org_Apps.getString("A_Ps_Id")); m++;
            Org_Apps[m][0]= new String("Last");
            //System.out.println(i+":"+Org_Positions_IdTitle[i-1][j-1]+Org_Positions_IdTitle[i-1][j]);
        }

        session.put("Org_Positions_IdTitle", getOrg_Positions_IdTitle());
        session.put("Org_Apps", getOrg_Apps());



        <s:iterator value="Org_Positions_IdTitle" id="P_Ps_Id" >
            <s:iterator value="Org_Apps" id="A_Ps_Id" >
                <s:if test="%{#P_Ps_Id==#A_Ps_Id} ">
                    <s:property value="Title" />        
                </s:if>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator>
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @Abdou Please ask you question. What is your problem.

Comment: Oh deeply sorry Guys, I have a problem with displaying the Title. my intention is to iterate over the two 2Dimentional arrays 1) Org_Positions_IdTitle which contains a)the ids of raised positions and b)their Titles. 2) Org_Apps which contains a)student Ids and b)ids of raised positions. So I want whenever the position Ids in the two arrays are checked equal to diplay the Title of the position. Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it should look something like that:

```jsp
<s:iterator value="firstArray" var="arr1">
  <s:iterator value="secondArray" var="arr2">
    <s:if test="#arr1[0] == #arr2[1]">
      <s:property value="#arr1[1]" />        
    </s:if>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Don't forget that you need setters/getters for your arrays in action class.

BTW `id` attribute in Struts2 tags was deprecated long time ago, use `var` instead.

Also consider changing your code to use maps instead of arrays. Then there is no need to iterate it on JSP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Aleksander, though I get :**Attribute var invalid for tag iterator according to TLD**. Also in the jsp I get the var1 and var2 underligned. I am trying for the moment to google this problem. I'd be thankful if you can help with that too :)

Comment: @Abdou: If you are using very old version of Struts2 then use `id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great aid I used the Id and it worke out. Once again thank you very much.

Comment: I am trying to voteitUp but it's saying VotingUp requires 15 reputations !?

Comment: @Abdou: Yep, you need 15 reputation points to voteup: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up.