# Iterating through 2D ArrayList and displaying it on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2, ognl

I tried looking this up but didn't find anything that answered my question.

So what I've got is something that looks like this:

```java
private List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

This has a getter / setter and is being populated by this line:

```
String[] name = new String[columnCount];
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++ ) {
  name[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(i+1);
  Array tempArray = rs.getArray(name[i]);
  data.add((List<String>) tempArray);
}
```

In my jsp I know I need something like this:

```jsp
<s:iterator value="data">
        <th><s:property/></th>
    </s:iterator>
</tr>
```

I'm stuck though on how to iterate a 2D array and if it matters that it's an `ArrayList`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iterate over two arrays in jsp using struts 2 tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144897/iterate-over-two-arrays-in-jsp-using-struts-2-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is a SQL type, you need to get a Java array to use with the iteratator tag.

```
data.add((List<String>) Arrays.asList(tempArray.getArray()));
```

On JSP you should use two nested iterator tags.

```
<s:iterator var="row" value="data">
  <tr>
  <s:iterator value="#row">
    <td><s:property/></td>
  </s:iterator>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```